# Automorphisms group of a structure is a closed subgroup of the permutations over $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology, model-theory, topological-groups, descriptive-set-theory

Here is the second part of Example $7)$ of Kechris' "Classical Descriptive Set Theory" (pp. $59-60$):

> More generally, consider a structure
>   $$\mathcal{A}=(A,(R_i)_{i\in I},(f_j)_{j\in J},(c_k)_{k\in K})$$
>   (in the sense of model theory) condisting of a set $A$, a family of relation $(R_i)_{i\in I}$, operations $(f_j)_{j\in J}$ and distinguished elements $(c_k)_{k\in K})$ on $A$.
>   Assume $A$ is countably infinite.
>   Let $Aut(\mathcal{A})$ be the group of automorphisms of $\mathcal{A}$.
>   Thinking, without loss of generally, of $A$ as being $\mathbb{N}$, $Aut(\mathcal{A})$ is a closed subgroup of $S(\mathbb{N})$ group of permutations over $\mathbb{N}$.

I don't see how to prove that $Aut(\mathcal{A})$ is **closed** in $S(\mathbb{N})$.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What's the topology?

Comment: It might be easier to think about proving that the **complement** of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathcal A)$ is **open** in $S(\mathbb N)$.

Comment: @ThinkingTorus I guess $S(\mathbb N)$ is topologized as a subspace of $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ with the Tychonoff product topology. So it has a subbase consisting of sets of the form $\{\alpha\in S(\mathbb N):\alpha(m)=n\}$.

Comment: The topology is that of pointwise convergence. $A$ doesn't have to be countable for $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal{A})$ to be closed in $S(A)$. So I'd rather write "Think, in view of this loss of generality" :)

Comment: Why separate those constants $c_k$ from the operations? A constant is just a 0-ary operation

Comment: @YCor I agree that one should view constants as $0$-ary functions. But in classical references on first-order logic and model theory, it's much more common to see constants treated separately. I'm sure that Kechris, in pointing out a connection to model theory in his book, just wanted to follow the traditional notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A permutation is an automorphism when it preserves the interpretations of all the basic relation, function, and constant symbols. But preserving the interpretation of the symbols is the same as *not failing* to preserve the symbols. So the idea is to check that "for every symbol in the language, for every possible way $\sigma$ could fail to preserve the symbol, $\sigma$ doesn't do that" is a closed condition.

More precisely: for any finite tuples $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$ in $\mathbb{N}^k$, there is an open set $$U(\overline{a},\overline{b}) = \{\sigma\in  S(\mathbb{N})\mid \sigma(\overline{a}) = \overline{b}\}.$$
It's complement is a closed set $$C(\overline{a},\overline{b}) = \{\sigma\in  S(\mathbb{N})\mid \sigma(\overline{a}) \neq \overline{b}\}.$$

Now the set of automorphisms of the structure $\mathcal{A}$ with domain $\mathbb{N}$ is the intersection of the following closed sets:

- For every $k$-ary relation symbol $R$ in the language, and for any pair of tuples $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$ in $\mathbb{N}^k$ such that $\mathcal{A}\models R(\overline{a})\not\leftrightarrow R(\overline{b})$, the closed set $C(\overline{a},\overline{b})$.
- For every $k$-ary function symbol $f$ in the language, for any pair of tuples  $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$ in $\mathbb{N}^k$, and for any element $d$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathcal{A}\models d\neq f(\overline{b})$, the closed set $C(\overline{a}f^{\mathcal{A}}(\overline{a}),\overline{b}d)$.
- For every constant symbol $c$ in the language, and for any element $b$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathcal{A}\models c\neq b$, the closed set $C(c^\mathcal{A},b)$.

---

More efficiently (but less explicitly), we can show that $\text{Aut}(\mathcal{A})$ is closed in $S(\mathbb{N})$ by showing that its complement is open, i.e. for every $\sigma\in S(\mathbb{N})\setminus \text{Aut}(\mathcal{A})$, $\sigma$ has an open neighborhood contained in 
$S(\mathbb{N})\setminus \text{Aut}(\mathcal{A})$.

Well, if $\sigma$ fails to be an automorphism, this is already witnessed by some finite tuple $\overline{a}$, in the sense there is some symbol in the language such that $\sigma$ fails to preserve this symbol because it maps $\overline{a}$ to $\overline{b} = \sigma(\overline{a})$. Then any permutation of $\mathbb{N}$ that maps $\overline{a}$ to $\overline{b}$ will fail to be an automorphism, so $U(\overline{a},\overline{b})$ is an open neighborhood of $\sigma$ in $S(\mathbb{N})\setminus \text{Aut}(\mathcal{A})$, as desired.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. Secondly, I have tried to work out the details in order to prove the closedness of such "$3$ kinds of sets", but I didn't succeed. For instance, if $R$ is a $k$-ary relation, following your idea, I want to show that $\{\sigma\in S(\Bbb{N})\mid \text{$\sigma$ preserves $R$}\}$ is closed in $S(\Bbb{N})$. But $\sigma$ preserves $R$ iff $\forall \overline{a}\in\Bbb{N}^k$ we have $\overline{a}\in R\iff\sigma(\overline{a})\in R$ and I simply don't see why it is closed... What is wrong/I miss? I apologize for the elementary explanation I need.

Comment: @LBJFS (1) Do you agree that the set I called $C(\overline{a},\overline{b})$ is closed? (2) The observation is that can rephrase "$\sigma$ preserves $R$" as $\forall \overline{a},\overline{b}\in \mathbb{N}^k\, ((\overline{a}\in R\not\leftrightarrow \overline{b}\in R)\rightarrow \sigma(\overline{a})\neq \overline{b})$. This is $\bigcap C(\overline{a},\overline{b})$, where the intersection is over all tuples $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$ such that $(\overline{a}\in R\not\leftrightarrow \overline{b}\in R)$.

Comment: I've also added another explanation to the end of the answer, in case you find that one easier to follow.

Comment: $(1)$ $C(\overline{a},\overline{b})$ is closed by definition of product topology, as you stated in your answer and I understand that. But I don't see why $(2)$ holds

Comment: Ok, I try to understand your edit. Thank you very much

Comment: Which part of (2) do you not understand? Is it the rephrasing of "$\sigma$ preserves $R$" or the translation of that logical formula into an intersection of closed sets? Or both?

Comment: The rephrasing of "$\sigma$ preserves $R$", sorry

Comment: @LBJFS That's ok! The formula I wrote is equivalent to $\forall \overline{a}, \overline{b}\in \mathbb{N}^k\, ((\sigma(\overline{a}) = \overline{b}) \rightarrow (\overline{a}\in R\leftrightarrow \overline{b}\in R))$, which is equivalent to $\forall \overline{a} (\overline{a}\in R \leftrightarrow \sigma(\overline{a})\in R)$, which is the definition of $\sigma$ preserving $R$.

Comment: I have understood the edit. About the first and more explicit answer, to prove that $\{\sigma\in S(\Bbb{N})\mid \overline{a}\in R\iff\sigma(\overline{a})\in R\}$ is closed, I wrote it (viewing $a \iff b$ as abbreviation of $(\neg a\land b)\lor (a\land \neg b)$) as $\{\sigma\in S(\Bbb{N}\mid \overline{a}\in R\land\sigma(\overline{a})\in R\}\cup\{\sigma\in S(\Bbb{N}\mid \overline{a}\notin R\land\sigma(\overline{a})\in R\}$, but I here I stuck. from your rephrase, from what do you deduce closedness?

Comment: As you have understood, I'm a beginner and for me it's very important to understand these lines of reasoning because they are the milestones for future developments (I tried to justify why I'm so annoying). However, I want to thank you for your patience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92572/discussion-between-alex-kruckman-and-lbjfs).